# Jenkins GitPlugin - how to find out what failed on a pre-build merge?

Tags: java, git, jenkins

We have Jenkins installed using GitPlugin to pull branches and merge them, as described in the [GitPlugin Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures).  However, when the merge fails there's no output saying why it failed, just that it didn't merge cleanly:

```
<snip>
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/labs/intro
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision 620c4373792b8cef6a3992b6676892479ed379b0 (origin/REV_4/REV-1234)
Merging Revision 620c4373792b8cef6a3992b6676892479ed379b0 (origin/REV_4/REV-1234) onto REV_4/integration
ERROR: Branch not suitable for integration as it does not merge cleanly
[JaCoCo plugin] Collecting JaCoCo coverage data...
<snip>
```

I can't duplicate this behavior locally.  It has something to do with the Git line ending settings.

Can anybody tell me how to squeeze more information out of Jenkins and the GitPlugin, so I can tell what files are failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isn't a way, since there's an [open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9947) about it, and also by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L1160) at least I don't see exception details recorded anywhere. They're lost.

Some options what you could do:

- merge the branch yourself and see if it helps
- make a fork of the plugin that saves the information somewhere or outputs it or
- run Jenkins using remote debugger, having a breakpoint at that point in code.

There are [instructions here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-run-debgger-on-a-remote-instance-of-jenkins-td4515398.html) to run Jenkins with a debugger:

> Add the following to the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS variable (separated by
>   spaces, surrounded by quotes):
>
> `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5678`
>
> So the full line may look something like:
>
> `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -DXX:MaxPermSize=512m -DXX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0"`
>
> Obviously change the port from 5678 to something else if you need.

Answer (score 0):

GIT Plugin prompts this error when there are file conflicts after git merge.
try locally merging both the branches and you can see.

One solution that can be used here is to perform git merge using ours/theirs strategies

```
    git checkout master
    git merge -X ours REV-1234
```

This will allow you to keeps current branch file-revisions for conflicting files.

```
    git checkout master
    git merge -X theirs REV-1234
```

This will allow you to keeps remote branch file-revisions for conflicting files.